# Conditional plugin dependency based on platform in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, yarnpkg, nativescript-vue

Is it possible to have a conditional package.json dependency based on the platform being built for, or, some hook that excludes / includes a dependency based on platform, when building a Nativescript 5.1 project?

My original plan was to use a Yarn alias to load 2 separate versions of a given package, then use `platform.isIOS` or `platform.isAndroid` to include only the right JS. However, under the hood the C++ shared object that both dependencies contain obviously has the same name - which gets clobbered, and both versions of the plugin end up using the same SO (defeating the point of the alias, as the bug I'm trying to get round is in the SO, not the plugin).

Comment: Usually the dependencies (C, C++, Java, etc.,) are placed in respective platforms folder, so it won't be copied to a different platform that was not intend to. Not sure which packages you are using, you might want to fix that.

Comment: That's true, however this is 2 package.json dependences for a single platform - my package.json has dependencies for version 4.3.1 and 4.4.1 of a given package, the latter via an alias.

Both of these dependencies have an SO file. Only 1 of those SO files ends up in `/platforms/android`. That's good. However I need to somehow state that Android gets the one from 4.3.1, and iOS gets the one from 4.4.1. At the moment having both dependecies means 1 of the SOs is clobbered.